# spring -> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

In my current spring project, when my application try execute this method:

```
  public void setPedido(Cliente current) {
    Pedido novo = new Pedido();
    novo.setData(new Date());
    novo.setListaDeProdutos(current.getCestaDeCompras());
    pedido.insert(novo);

    if(current.getListaDePedidos() == null)
      current.setListaDePedidos(new ArrayList<Pedido>());

    current.getListaDePedidos().add(novo);
    current.getCestaDeCompras().clear();
    cliente.update(current);
  }
```

I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.setCurrentSession(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:633)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.WrapVisitor.processCollection(WrapVisitor.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:121)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.WrapVisitor.processValue(WrapVisitor.java:125)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processEntityPropertyValues(AbstractVisitor.java:76)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.visitCollectionsBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:372)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:273)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.persist(Unknown Source)
        at org.store.generic.persistence.Dao.insert(Dao.java:29)
        at org.store.generic.persistence.Dao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ac46d9f5.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
```

my Dao class (where the method insert is placed) is this:

```
public class Dao<E> {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory factory;

    protected Class<? extends Model> clazz;

    public Dao(Class<? extends Model> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return factory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void insert(E object) {
        EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.persist(object);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    ...
}
```

I also tried add the annotation @Transaction in the methods insert, update and delete from Dao class, and in the methods which use them in the service class, but the same problem happens.

Anyone can see what I am doing wrong here?

ps.: the entity class I am trying to save is that:

```
@Entity
public class Pedido extends Model {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Order(value = 1)
  private Integer id;

  @Order(value = 2)
  private Date data;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name="listaDeProdutos", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_pedido")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_produto")})
  @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
  @Order(value = 3)
  private List<Produto> listaDeProdutos;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, In fact the problem which was generating this error was due to a missing close() instruction in the method from Dao class. I modify the code to this:

```
public void insert(E object) {
    EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.persist(object);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    entityManager.close();
}
```

and now all works fine.